# Password Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, hash, passwords

Could anyone tell me what type of Algotithm/Hash Function the following passwords use?

password: `scrambled text`

```
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh : .!_-*/P_.!_-*/P
iiiiiiiiiiiiiii : / ^,+.Q^/ ^,+.Q
jjjjjjjjjjjjjjj : ,#]/(-R],#]/(-R
kkkkkkkkkkkkkkk : -"\.),S\-"\.),S
lllllllllllllll : *%[).+T[*%[).+T
```

Comment: It doesn't look like a strong function.

Comment: A bad one. The last character should not be obviously correlated.

Answer (score 3):

It just looks like

```
char[i] = someMap[i%6, char[i%6]]
```

and the `someMap[i]` submaps are sequentially taken from ascii.

You don't have to guess the exact formula to reproduce it : a char of ascii code `c` at index `i%6` always give the same char, so, with 127 tests (or more if you want to handle more chars), you can build your own map of dimension `127` x `6`.

Note that it's impossible with your small test data to be sure there is no cumulative function in which a permutation could be function of the precedent char.